# How to write an even or odd program in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

My instructions are "Write a program that prompts the user for a number, then counts up (a ‘for’ loop) from one to that number and prints whether that loop number is even or odd (which will require an ‘if-else’ structure inside the loop)." So it needs to list:
1 is odd
2 is even 
3 is odd...

```
public class AssmtEvenOrOddJulianP {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //variable
  int num = 0;

  //input
  System.out.print("\nEnter a number less than 100: ");
  num = Expo.enterInt();

  //output
  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
     if ((num % 2) == 0)
     System.out.print("\n" + i + " Is Even");       
     else if ((num % 2) >= 0)
     System.out.print("\n" + i + " Is Odd");
```

Right now if I input 3 it will print:
1 is odd
2 is odd
3 is odd

Comment: You should check `i`, not `num`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, should've looked closer.

Comment: A remark on your code: Even when possible, you should never neglect opening and closing parenthesis around one-line `for`-. `if`-, `else`-, ... statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Minor mistake:

You should calculate the remainder of `i` by 2, not `num` by 2.

#### Always wrap `for` and `if`/`else` blocks in curly braces:

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + i + " Is Even");
    } else if ((num % 2) >= 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + i + " Is Odd");
    }
}
```

#### Avoid using redundant parantheses:

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + i + " Is Even");
    } else if (num % 2 >= 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + i + " Is Odd");
    }
}
```

#### The `else if` condition has a minor bug that is "unreachable" right now, but could cause pain in the future

`num % 2 >= 0` should be `i % 2 < 0 || i % 2 > 0`

#### The `else if` condition can be simplified to `else`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + i + " Is Even");
    } else {
        System.out.print("\n" + i + " Is Odd");
    }
}
```

### Final result:

With some other minor improvements:

```
public class EvenOdd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // input
        System.out.print("\nEnter a number less than 100: ");

        // variable
        int num = Expo.enterInt();

        System.out.println();

        // output
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i + " Is Even");
            } else {
                System.out.println(i + " Is Odd");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, in Java 8+, `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, num).forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%d Is %s%n", i, i % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd"));`

Answer (score -1):

The Following program will help you . for odd and Even number we need to divide by 2 and if number is divisible by 2 then number is Even Number (in this case reminder will be 0) and if the reminder is 1 then its Odd Number

```
public class EvenAndOddNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i + " is even number");
        } else {
            System.out.println(i + " is odd number");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You did the OP's (original poster's) job for him/her but didn't answer their (implied) question of where they made their mistake.